# HP ML115 with P400 Smart Array Controller

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP ML115 server I have installed a HP P400 Smart Array Controller card, I also have 4 x 1TB Samsung Hard drives.

I'm unable to get the the controller to detect the hard drives, I have changed the drives to SATA 1.5G without luck, I have also tried connecting a single 80GB Maxtor drive without luck

The controller shows up just after boot and tries to initialize, The controller does not show up in the POST prompt, although I can see the controller when booting off a ACU CD

THe controller firmware is a little old v4.12 but I have no way to update it.

Any ideas on how I can get this going?

Comment: Why can't you upgrade\reflash the firmware? There appears to be an updated version on the HP support Web site. http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1157689&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=1157687&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005

Comment: Download the Firmware Maint CD from HP and update the P400 (any any other hardware it finds): http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-cdee9b93a98c43bb95653f9d41

Answer (score 2):

Fran Garcia is correct, you can't just pick your own SATA disks with those controllers - [HERE](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12400_na/12400_na.html)'s the quickspecs to help you choose the correct disk part numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just plug any random disk you buy at bestbuy -- you'll need to install HP-provided disk with supported disk firmware (the P400 controllers check for this).

Regards

Comment: I haven't tried any Samsung drives, but WDC, Hitachi, Seagate all seem to work well with the P400 series. But you definitely need the newest firmware for the larger drives (>1TB); and certain drives (::cough WD::) need updated firmware too.